# Inserting element in doctrine listener

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have setup a doctrine listener which is fired on different database actions and creates a log entity and insert it into the database.

```
class FOO { 
 // [...]
 public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
 {
     foreach ($args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
                $this->createLog('edit', $entity);
     }
 }


 private function createLog($action, $entity)
 {
        if ($entity instanceof Log) {
            return;
        }
        $log = new Log;
        $log->setAction($action);
        $log->setTime(new \DateTime);
        $log->setForeignId($entity->getId());
        $log->setUser($this->getUser());
        $t            = explode('\\', get_class($entity));
        $entity_class = strtolower(end($t));
        $log->setEntity($entity_class);
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($log);
  }
// [...]
}
```

When I update an object, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

In the profiler I see this query:

> INSERT INTO vvg_logs (action, entity, foreign_id, user_id, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>
> Parameters: { }

How could I resolve this problem?

**UPDATE**
Here is my new topic connecting to this question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606450/symfony2-inserting-element-inside-doctrine-postpersist-listener)

Comment: It seems the question you are linking has been removed. Could you please provide more information about how you solved this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because when `onFlush` is called, all changes are already calculated and you need to refresh them if you change your entity or create a new entity.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$logMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata('Your\LogClass');
...
$em->persist($log);
$uow->computeChangeSet($logMetadata, $log);
```

---

**For postPersist:**

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
$log = new Log;
...

$logMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata('Your\LogClass');
$className = $logMetadata->name;
$persister = $this->getEntityPersister($className);
$persister->addInsert($log);
$uow->computeChangeSet($classMeta, $logEntry);
$postInsertIds = $persister->executeInserts();

if ($postInsertIds) {
    foreach ($postInsertIds as $id => $entity) {
        $idField = $logMetadata->identifier[0];
        $logMetadata->reflFields[$idField]->setValue($entity, $id);
        $this->addToIdentityMap($entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I persist a new Log in the postPersist listener? The problem is, that in the commit method of UnitOfWork, the insertations happen first, but when my listener gets fired, the insertations are over, so my log wont be inserted. I tried to call the commit method from my listener, but that causes other entityy objects to be inserted twice. What I'd like to achieve is to recall the commit after everything is done. If you know an alternative solution, that is fine, too.

Comment: @DavidFrank updated. I think you don't need to call the commit method again.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The commit contains this:
   `if ($this->entityInsertions) {
                foreach ($commitOrder as $class) {
                    $this->executeInserts($class);
                }
            }`
Originally the commitOrder does not contain the Log class, so regardless my log is in the scheduled insertations, the system does not execute the insertation.

Comment: Here is my new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606450/symfony2-inserting-element-inside-doctrine-postpersist-listener

Comment: @DavidFrank Right.. I can only think up the solution in the update answer. Try it, i will check it tomorrow.

Comment: Any new ideas? As I said earlier, your new piece of code doesnt work for me. After studying the code of UnitOfWork, I think the reason is that before the first insertation happens, the system prepares the changelist and when I schedule an insert, it doesnt get recorded into the changelist. If you know a solution, please post it into my new topic, so I can upvote / accept your answer for this different problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DavidFrank: did you check the code from yesterday? It doesn't involve UoW now.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed that you'd updated your postPersist solution. I had to add a recalculateChangeSet function call to your code, I refactorized a bit, now it works like a charm. You are AWESOME! Thank you very much. 1 question: what does the second part of your code do(starting from if($postInsertIds)). I omitted that part from my version, but it still works. Thank you one more time! If you post this solution to my other topic, I can accept it so you gain more points(you deserve it).

Comment: The second part adds the entity to IdentifyMap, so you won't have two objects with the same id. Yes. it can be omitted in this case, since a log entity won't be used in another place. You better post the code you refactored in your second question, so if anyone needs it, they'll get working code ;)