# Translate on OnFlush Event with Gedmo

Tags: symfony

I have a problem with my listener.

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        if($entity->getTranslatable() == 1){
            $translation = $this->translate($entity);

            $repository = $em->getRepository('ByJM\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation\ChambreTranslation');

            $repository
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'fr', $translation['fr'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'en', $translation['en'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'es', $translation['es'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'it', $translation['it'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'nl', $translation['nl'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'pt', $translation['pt'])
            ; 

            $md = $em->getClassMetadata('ByJM\AdminBundle\Entity\Chambre');
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($md, $entity);
        }
    }

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if($entity->getTranslatable() == 1){
            $translation = $this->translate($entity);

            $repository = $em->getRepository('ByJM\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation\ChambreTranslation');

            $repository
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'fr', $translation['fr'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'en', $translation['en'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'es', $translation['es'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'it', $translation['it'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'nl', $translation['nl'])
                ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'pt', $translation['pt'])
            ; 

            $em->persist($entity);

            $md = $em->getClassMetadata('ByJM\AdminBundle\Entity\Chambre');
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($md, $entity);
        }
    }         
}
```

And i have this error: 
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO chambre_translations (locale, object_class, field, foreign_key, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)':

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

If anyone have a solution for me, it would be awesome!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue related to Gedmo.

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583058/inserting-element-in-doctrine-listener), `onFlush` is called, all changes are already calculated and you need to refresh them if you change your entity or create a new entity.

So you need to add an `$em->persist($entity);`

Can you try this ? please

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
{
     $em = $args->getEntityManager();
     $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

     $entities = array_merge(
         $uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions(),
         $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates()
     );

     foreach ($entities as $entity) {
         if($entity->getTranslatable() == 1){
               $translation = $this->translate($entity);

               $repository = $em->getRepository('ByJM\AdminBundle\Entity\Translation\ChambreTranslation');

               $repository
                     ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'fr', $translation['fr'])
                     ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'en', $translation['en'])
                     ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'es', $translation['es'])
                     ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'it', $translation['it'])
                     ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'nl', $translation['nl'])
                     ->translate($entity, 'nom', 'pt', $translation['pt']); 

               $em->persist($entity);
               $md = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
               $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($md, $entity);
         }

     }
}
```